# Mongo: Can i upsert(insert or update if data already exists) a list of data on the basis of a unique key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of data-

```
{bookName: book1,
bookId: bookId1,
bookType: type1,
publisher: publisher1,
uniqueCombo: "bookId" + "publisher"}
```

My unique identifier in this case if uniqueCombo. I want to upsert these data to my mongo collection on the basis of the uniqueCombo. If the unique uniqueCombo of the latest data is not present in the collection then inset otherwise update the documents where the uniqueCombo is found.

I can use loop here and upsert the data one by one but i do not want to use loop. Or I can use unique index on the field uniqueCombo which will do the job but I need to know if any other way is there to achieve this.

I am using MongoDB shell version v4.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `uniqueCombo` is renamed to `_id`, you will have to use a loop. However, you can use a bulk operator to build it into a single operation.

```js
var bulk = db.users.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();


// foreach book
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  var book = books[i];
  bulk.find({
    uniqueCombo: book.bookId + book.publisher
  }).upsert().updateOne({
    {
      bookName: book.bookName,
      bookId: book.bookId,
      bookType: book.bookType,
      publisher: book.publisher,
      uniqueCombo: book.bookId + book.publisher
    }
  });

}

bulk.execute();
```